# Getting BusyPoolException com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.QueryExecutor , what wrong me doing?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1 ,spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1 with java8 and apache cassandra 3.0 version.

I have my spark-submit or spark cluster environment as below to load 2 billion records.

```
--executor-cores 3 
--executor-memory 9g 
--num-executors 5 
--driver-cores 2 
--driver-memory 4g
```

> Using following configurration

```
cassandra.concurrent.writes=1500
cassandra.output.batch.size.rows=10
cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes=2048
cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key=partition 
cassandra.output.consistency.level=LOCAL_QUORUM
cassandra.output.batch.grouping.buffer.size=3000
cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec=128
```

Job is taking around 2 hrs , it really huge time

When I check logs I see
 WARN  com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.QueryExecutor - BusyPoolException

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect value for `cassandra.concurrent.writes` - this means that you're sending 1500 concurrent batches at the same time. But by default, [Java driver allows 1024 simultaneous requests](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/pooling/#simultaneous-requests-per-connection).  And usually, if you have too high number for this parameter, could lead to overload of the nodes, and as result - retries for tasks.

Also, other settings are incorrect - if you sepcify `cassandra.output.batch.size.rows`, then its value overrides the value of `cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes`. See [corresponding section of the Spark Cassandra Connector reference](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters) for more details.

One of the aspects of performance tuning is to have correct number of Spark partitions, so you reach good parallelism - but this really depends on your code, how many nodes in Cassandra cluster, etc.

P.S. Also, please note that configuration parameters should be started with `spark.cassandra.`, not with simple `cassandra.` - if you specified them in this form, then these parameters are ignored and defaults are used.

Comment: @BdLearner The partition key should be selected based on the access patterns that are used for fetching data from Cassandra - it's really depends on your use case, and generally hard to say. I would recommend to take DS220 course on https://academy.datastax.com/ - there are some examples on how you can design the partition key correctly